# Using parameters or existing vars in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

I added CSS to a checkbox and it works just fine.
I use a local file (named check.png) to use as the check background image and crop it inside the checkbox area.

Here are two checkboxes one checked and one unchecked

[image: enter link description here]

Now I'd like to know if it's possible, instead of manually setting 25px in the CSS file, to get the background image's real width and height and set the width to background.width and the height to background.height/2.

That would allow to have it automatically resize if I ever change check.png and still work properly

EDIT: I think I was misunderstood. I want the box to fit the background image, not the image to fit the box. I'll try the opposite anyway

EDIT2: Okay Nvm Apparently fitting the background in the box was a better idea than fitting the box in the image. Thanks :D

Comment: `background-size` is probably what you were looking for. Also check out `background-position` in case you want to position the image in certain ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to write the exact `width` and `height`.
To scale the background image to fit inside its container, you can simply use:

```
background-size:contain;
```

Comment: `background-size:contain;` this works only for height or width not for both

Answer (score 0):

set

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript to get image width and height:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  alert(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TObz.png';
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to do it exclusively using CSS? Thanks anyway

Comment: If you need the container to adapt to the image size dynamically I'm afraid you'll have to use javascript

Comment: I see thank you. Well the other way around (image fit in container) worked as I wanted too, thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

@Durga's answer fits your need.

However, letting the resource file to decide your DOM component size seems not to be the best practice, doing the opposite way (use css to auto fit the image to your container, as @Koby suggested) is usually preferred.